# Weblogic managed server logs printing threadID

Tags: logging, weblogic

I have a managed Server of weblogic which creates a log file managed1.log. How can I configure it not to print the below lines(threadID) ? I tried from admin server configuration, log4j filtering etc but nothing helps ?

1247213 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)']

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: why do you even care ??

Comment: I am doing some elk stuff and I have thread info in json there . I don’t need it . Just to make log file just to contain only Jsons

Comment: WebLogic server's logs cannot be customized except for the date format. Configure logstash to ignore unnecessary data.

Comment: Yes thats true !! @EmmanuelCollin.. So what I did was to print the Console logs in the managed1.out which eventually does not print those above lines and my log looks pretty decent now :-) So I have been able to do it in some way ..... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i want to answer my own question here as it can be helpful to someone... So eventually What I did was to figure out that Console logs by Weblogic does not print those extra lines above and they are printed in the managed server out logs. By changing additivity in log4j.xml I filtered all the Serverlogs to some other file and achieved my goal.